# Import Contacts creating dupes despite dedupe rules

Tags: import, duplicate-contacts

We are currently updating a member database with returning and new students/contacts. In the past we have been able to import lists updating the returning students, but now new duplicate records are being created for each of our returning students. I have tried importing using several dedupe rules (including ones that worked in prior years) and also selecting update and skip, but still get duplicates.

What am I missing? Since last year, I have udpated WordPress, CiviCRM and PHP, but I don't know if that could cause this sort of problem. Any suggestions are welcome.

CiviCRM 4.7.31
Wordpress 4.9.6
PHP 7.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is just to use the Contact ID if it is in your file.

Are you importing to the same location type? It does not dedupe a given data point if importing on a different location type.

I've noticed that you must set your desired dedupe rule to be unsupervised. Selecting a rule that is not marked unsupervised hasn't worked lately and is probably a bug.

I believe this is related [Import Contacts with dedupe rules](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/24871/import-contacts-with-dedupe-rules)

Comment: Changing the rules to unsupervised seemed to do the trick!